# Firestore Update in realtime listener in Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a listener with Firestore that allows me to view the update in real time, but unfortunately I can not. Here is a portion of my code:

```
db.collection('users/user')
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
        if (change.type === "added") {
          console.log("New user: ", change.doc.data());
        }
        if (change.type === "modified") {
          console.log("Modified user: ", change.doc.data());
          const data = {
            id: change.oldIndex,
            name: change.doc.data().name,
            surname: change.doc.data().surname
          };
          vm.users.push(data);
        }
        if (change.type === "removed") {
          console.log("Removed user: ", change.doc.data());
        }
      });
    });
```

when the event "modified" happens I do not see any change in page, but if I have the result printed in the console I see the new data correctly.

How can I solve?

Comment: Have you defined ```users``` as array in data function?

Comment: Please show the entire code of your Vue.js component.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the code part shared in this question, it is not obvious how or where `user` array constructed or used. Is it a `prop`, `data` or `state-container` data?

Overall, your listener functions looks good. That's why you see your data written on console. The missing part here is how to assign it to use on front-end.

In case you are using Vuex state container, then mutations are way to go. `Props` can lost on refresh. Data or computed properties would be better fit for live listening data from firestore.

If it is component data, then you might want to re-try with `this` keyword.